# What is the mechanism that display my online friends?

Tags: facebook, multi-friend-selector

I'm developing a game and i want display all online friend for a specific player.

I already would use a online status field in my player class and display all players and test who have the online status true.

Any suggestion please ?? can i simulate the mechanism used by Facebook to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`FQL Query` can return a array of `active`, `idle` and `offline` friends

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_square, online_presence
            FROM user
            WHERE online_presence IN ('active', 'idle')
            AND uid IN (
                SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() 
            )
```

it requires the `friends_online_presence` permissions otherwise the `data` array would be NULL

Source: [Fetch Online Friends List With Facebook Graph Api](http://qpleple.com/fetch-online-friends-list-with-facebook-graph-api/)

Comment: that's Facebook case, in my case i have a list of players that i would like to know if there are connected or not, i wanted to add a online field in my entity but it will be update for each time the player is connected or disconnected. so, this will be very expansive for me knowing that i use Google app engine data store thanks.